# How to increase speed of file tranfer via FileZilla(FTP uploads)

Tags: ftp

Recently i came to notice that my hosting file transfer rate is pretty slow while my firms ftp uploading goes in lightning speed. Why is this huge difference.

Both the accounts have shared hosting with unlimited bandwidth. But in my ftp, it literally takes half a second to transfer a file while in my firm's ftp almost 100 files can be transferred in same time.

Is there something i can do via my Cpanel to increase the speed of the ftp file transfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, you can't increase upload speeds via CPanel. This is purely a function of the link speed your hosting provider is giving you. Bandwidth does not relate to speed in this case. You might have "unlimited" monthly data, but be capped at 10MBits (not a lot). In practice there's a very real limit to how much data you can move.

If you want fast FTP speeds, you probably need a dedicated provider with an explicit network link speed SLA.

Answer (score 1):

You can never guarantee the speed when it comes to shared hosting. This is why it's so cheap. Search around for some recommended shared hosting providers in your country, and switch the site over to them.